# How to handle special characters like single/double quotes/space inside XPATH JAVA

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on element using below code and its working fine if variable does not have special characters.

Values that passed in variable are:

```
Product  Passed
Test Message -> Failed
Double Units 13/2" -> failed
```

I cannot go with partial text, because sometimes only difference between two element is special character.

```
String Answertoselect = ElementName.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");
String selectanswer = Answertoselect.replaceAll(" ", "${nbsp}");
```

Comment: XPath doesn't have an escaping mechanism - you can put single quotes in a double quoted string and vice versa, but it's impossible to put both single and double quote characters in the same xpath string literal.